# Procedure to fix table builds cci to ci

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

All our platform team has asked our team to refrain from using unnecessary Clustered Columnstore

I'm trying to create a proc that we can use
pass in the table
and the index column.

I'm getting an error when trying to create
"Parse error at line: 25, column: 14: Incorrect syntax near '@A'"

I don't see an issue; what am I missing?

```
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [lab03].[Sproc_TableCCItoCI] @Table [NVARCHAR](150),@TheColumn [NVARCHAR](150) 
AS

-- exec lab03.Sproc_TableCCItoCI @param1 = '', @param2 = '' 



-- ==========================================================================================================================================================================
-- File Name:   
--  
-- Purpose: Fix tables built using clustered - columnstore 

-- 
-- Version  Date        Changed by              Description
-- -------  ----------  -------------------     -------------------------------------------
-- 1.0      2021-07-22  Sxxx                Move to prod 
-- 
-- ==========================================================================================================================================================================
-- converting Clustered Columnstore(CCI) index to Clustered Index (CI) 

DECLARE @A Varchar(6)
SET @A = 'lab16.'


CREATE TABLE @A + @Table + '_convert'  
WITH (   
       DISTRIBUTION = HASH (@TheColumn),
       CLUSTERED INDEX  (@TheColumn)
)
AS  
SELECT  
    * 
FROM @A + @Table 

--save current table just in case, you’ll drop this as soon as process is complete
  RENAME OBJECT @A + @Table TO  @Table + '_Hold'  
--renames new table to the existing name
RENAME OBJECT @A + @Table + '_convert'  TO @Table;   

--validate if desired then drop the hold table
DROP TABLE @A + @Table +'_Hold';



GO
```

Comment: You cannot parameterize object names. You will need dynamic sql to do this. And what about `@A` is variable? I suggest you write static code and get it working first, before you attempt the dynamic version. There are other flaws to be discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to understand dynamic SQL better and I can highly recommend Erland Sommarskog's excellent article '[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)'.

I've adapted an example from our Synapse db which is doing something similar and shows a method of parameterising dynamic sql plus doing some error checking in Synapse which is worthwhile when things go wrong.  Dedicated SQL Pools do not currently support the `RETURN` statement so just kind of ploughs on when errors occur so that's why it's good to collect as much info as possible through the error messages.  See what you think of this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_convertTableToCI') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC dbo.usp_convertTableToCI;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.usp_convertTableToCI

    @schemaName SYSNAME, 
    @tableName SYSNAME,
    @columnName SYSNAME,
    @debug_yn BIT

AS

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Check schema exists
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE [name] = @schemaName )
    RAISERROR( 'Source schema [%s] does not exist.', 16, 1, @schemaName );

-- Check table exists
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = @schemaName AND [name] = @tableName )
    RAISERROR( 'Source table [%s].[%s] does not exist.', 16, 1, @schemaName, @tableName );

-- Check column exists
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) = @schemaName AND OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = @tableName AND [name] = @columnName )
    RAISERROR( 'Column [%s] does not exist in table [%s].[%s].', 16, 1, @columnName, @schemaName, @tableName );


-- Assemble the dynamic SQL to swap the table over to clustered index
SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE @schemaName.@tableName_convert  
WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( @columnName ),
    CLUSTERED INDEX ( @columnName )
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM @schemaName.@tableName;

-- Save current table just in case, you’ll drop this as soon as process is complete
RENAME OBJECT @schemaName.@tableName TO  @tableName_Hold

-- Renames new table to the existing name
RENAME OBJECT @schemaName.@tableName_convert TO @tableName;   

-- Validate if desired then drop the hold table
--DROP TABLE @schemaName.@tableName_Hold;'

-- Replace the variable names
SET @sql = REPLACE( 
    REPLACE( 
        REPLACE( @sql, '@schemaName', @schemaName ), 
            '@tableName', @tableName ), 
        '@columnName', @columnName )


IF @debug_yn = 1
    PRINT @sql;
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC(@sql);
END
GO
```

I would strongly suggest giving it some thorough tests for your scenarios.